# opennlp chunker and postag results

Tags: opennlp

Java - opennlp

I am new to opennlp and i am try to analyze the sentence and have the post tag and chunk result but I could not understand the values meaning. Is there any table which can explain the post tag and chunk result values full form meaning ?

```
Tokens: [My, name, is, Chris, corrale, and, I, live, in, Philadelphia, USA, .]
Post Tags: [PRP$, NN, VBZ, NNP, NN, CC, PRP, VBP, IN, NNP, NNP, .]
chunk Result: [B-NP, I-NP, B-VP, B-NP, I-NP, O, B-NP, B-VP, B-PP, B-NP, I-NP, O]
```

Comment: In my case (using OpenNLP.net), I get tags which aren't available in the Penn Treebank link below, do you guys have any idea what is going on here? Weird tags that I get: PROP ; ADV

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The POS tags are from the [Penn Treebank tagset](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html). The chunks are noun phrases (NP), verb phrases (VP), and prepositions (PP). "B-.." marks the beginning of such a phrase, "I-.." means something like "inner", i.e. the phrase continues here (see [OpenNLP docs](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.chunker.training)).

Answer (score 11):

S -> Simple declarative clause, i.e. one that is not introduced by a
(possible empty) subordinating
     conjunction or a wh-word and that does not exhibit subject-verb
inversion.

SBAR -> Clause introduced by a (possibly empty) subordinating conjunction.

SBARQ -> Direct question introduced by a wh-word or a wh-phrase.
         Indirect questions and relative clauses should be bracketed as
SBAR, not SBARQ.

SINV -> Inverted declarative sentence, i.e. one in which the subject
follows the tensed verb or modal.

SQ -> Inverted yes/no question, or main clause of a wh-question, following
the wh-phrase in SBARQ.

ADJP -> Adjective Phrase.

ADVP -> Adverb Phrase.

CONJP -> Conjunction Phrase.

FRAG -> Fragment.

INTJ -> Interjection. Corresponds approximately to the part-of-speech tag
UH.

LST -> List marker. Includes surrounding punctuation.

NAC -> Not a Constituent; used to show the scope of certain prenominal
modifiers within an NP.

NP -> Noun Phrase.

NX -> Used within certain complex NPs to mark the head of the NP.
Corresponds very roughly to N-bar

PP -> Prepositional Phrase.

PRN -> Parenthetical.

PRT -> Particle. Category for words that should be tagged RP.

QP -> Quantifier Phrase (i.e. complex measure/amount phrase); used within
NP.

RRC -> Reduced Relative Clause.

UCP -> Unlike Coordinated Phrase.

VP -> Verb Phrase.

WHADJP -> Wh-adjective Phrase. Adjectival phrase containing a wh-adverb, as
in how hot.

WHAVP -> Wh-adverb Phrase. Introduces a clause with an NP gap. May be null
(containing the 0 complementizer)
         or lexical, containing a wh-adverb such as how or why.

WHNP -> Wh-noun Phrase. Introduces a clause with an NP gap. May be null
(containing the 0 complementizer)
        or lexical, containing some wh-word, e.g. who, which book, whose
daughter, none of which, or how
        many leopards.

WHPP -> Wh-prepositional Phrase. Prepositional phrase containing a wh-noun
phrase
        (such as of which or by whose authority) that either introduces a
PP gap or is contained by a WHNP.

X ->  Unknown, uncertain, or unbracketable. X is often used for bracketing
typos and in bracketing
      the...the-constructions.

Credit: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/opennlp-users/201402.mbox/%3CCACQuOSXOeyw2O-AZtW3m=iABo1=3cpZOdPiWFXoNwN-SVWo4gQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the [POSTag list](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.com/2015/02/penn-treebank-pos-tags-in-natural.html) to get the tags details.

Chunk tags like "**B-NP**" are made up of two or three parts:
**First part**:

```
B - marks the beginning of a chunk
I - marks the continuation of a chunk
E - marks the end of a chunk
```

As a chunk,it may be only one word long (like "She" in the example above), it can be both beginning and end of a chunk at the same time.

**Second part**:

```
NP - noun chunk
VP - verb chunk
```

For more reference you can refer the  [OpenNLP Documentation](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.parser.chunking).